# Query with a list of elements

Tags: php, mysql

In my php code, there is a variable that contain a list of ID separated by ',' ( this variable can contains up to 6000 elements ):

```
$var = "12,54,452,122,543,82,11,756,2343,5676,122,995,21,5331,832,271885,19";
```

This is my users table in mysql:

```
users: id, username, password
```

What is the best query to return all rows of users table with one of that ID ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM users
           WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', explode(',', $var))) . ')';
```

This is the query to do that. Just execute it in any way you like better

PS: where do you get that string from? There is a chance you need to learn about Normal Forms

Comment: @xRobot: because I forgot to `implode` it back. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use IN in your SQL statement e.g
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id IN (' . $var . ')